# Android Studio não roda projeto nenhum

Tags: android, android-studio, windows

Esse é o erro que sempre aparece. Não consigo rodar nem nos emuladores, nem no meu aparelho. Já tentei desinstalar e instalar de novo, já tentei tirar e colocar de volta todos os SDK (sem sucesso, nem desinstalou, só desinstalando o programa todo), tentei usar uma versão desatualizada do programa e nada adiantou. O que pode ser?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Deve ter um determinado serviço (traccar) que estava em execução no seu PC. Tenta reiniciá-lo e encerrar os processos `adb.exe`, assim o Android Studio deve voltar a funcionar normalmente. Se volta a acontecer, tenta reiniciar o serviço e encerrar os processos `adb.exe`.

Caso não funcione pode ser que ele não esta conseguindo achar o SDK, verifique se a estrutura do seu projeto está apontando para o local válido do SDK

Comment: Descobri o problema amigo. Parece que meu antivírus deixou os processos adb.exe em quarentena não tenho ideia do porque. Restaurei e já voltou a funcionar. Obrigado pela atenção :)